# Can I store data in Redis more than its RAM size by any means?

Tags: redis, in-memory-database, spring-data-redis

I have redis server with 39GB RAM. Can I store more 39GB of data in redis using any means like Disk persistence(RDB or AOF)?

Comment: You can't store more than RAM size, in that case, Redis will be removed most old data.

Comment: ElastiCache Redis now supports data tiering. Data tiering provides a new cost optimal option for storing data in Redis by utilizing lower-cost local NVMe SSDs in each cluster node in addition to storing data in memory. It is ideal for workloads that access up to 20 percent of their overall dataset regularly, and for applications that can tolerate additional latency when accessing data on SSD. More details about data tiering can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/data-tiering.html).

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't if you talk about open source version. Here's an explanation from [Redis FAQ](https://redis.io/topics/faq#i-like-redis39s-high-level-operations-and-features-but-i-don39t-like-that-it-keeps-everything-in-memory-and-i-can39t-have-a-dataset-larger-than-memory-are-there-any-plans-to-change-this)

If you use Redis Enterprise take a look [Redis on Flash](https://docs.redislabs.com/latest/rs/concepts/memory-architecture/redis-flash/)